# Detecting which control is active

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, listbox, focus

I have a setup with a textbox and a listbox in which I want the listbox to be visible only when either the textbox or the listbox is focused. To begin with the listbox will be invisible. Then as the textbox is focused the listbox should be visible. Only when either looses focus and neither receives it should the listbox become invisible again. So what I want to achieve is the following to be true at all times:

`listBox.Visible = textBox.Focused || listBox.Focused`

In my solution the textbox and/or the listbox can be a specialization of the standard type (if this simplifies the solution).

I've tried listening on both controls LostFocus and GotFocus events and setting the visibility of the listbox there. However the GotFocus event is never called on the listbox since I turn it invisible when the textbox looses focus.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to achieve this? My backup plan (which I dislike) is to have a timer start when one looses focus and stop if the other receives focus. So a "cleaner" way of achieving it would be greatly appreciated ;)

**Edit:** I am developing this to be used as a .NET WinForms custom control.

**Edit 2:**

**It seems that I haven't explained myself quite good enough. So I'll try to explain what I want to achieve more explicitly.**

What I am creating a new type of TextBox (inheriting an existing type of TextBox I build some years ago). The TextBox is currently functioning as a generic collection (including a subtype that implements IList) of objects. The TextBox defines a ListBox which displays a subset of the elements in the collection based on a set of criteria. As the TextBox is added to a parent control, so is the ListBox. Thus the two work as a search-for-element-in-a-collection kind of setup. Sort of the same thing as when your browser makes suggestions as you start typing.

I am using this setup instead of a UserControl containing both controls because the latter would result in either the usercontrol being the size of both controls or (when the size matches the TextBox) the ListBox being invisible.

I realize that I could opt to handle GotFocus or Enter events on all controls in the form to which this control is added. This is a quite straightforward approach which I have thought of, but I would greatly prefer to write a control which does not listen on each and every other control in the form.

I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to add an `Enter` event handler to *all other* controls on the form.

```
private void OtherControls_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox.Visible = false;
}
```

**Edit:**
*Examples are for WinForms but should work with WPF aswell.*

If the custom control contains only the `TextBox` and `ListBox`then you add an event to the `TextBox` to set the `ListBox` visible:

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

If there are other controls you add the `OtherControls_Enter` event handler to them.

On the `Leave` event of the custom control you add something like:

```
private void userControl11_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  userControl11.Controls["listbox1"].Visible = false;
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Even better is to expose the `ListBox` from within the Custom Control:

```
public ListBox TheListBox { get { return listBox1; } }
```

and then:

```
private void userControl11_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  userControl11.TheListBox.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: My only issue with this approach is that I'm developing a custom control (which i probably should have mentioned) and thus I would have to add handlers to all controls as this custom control is added to a form or panel for that matter. The process of adding/removing a all these handlers (including when adding/removing controls to the form) will quickly result in a clutter of events. Also, there is no telling what other kind of handlers are added to the controls.

Comment: Also, there is no "OnFocus" event. I assumed you meant the "GotFocus" event and that your event handler was named appropriately.

Comment: What technology are you using? WPF? ASP.NET? WinForms? What does the custom control contain? The TextBox and ListBox only?

Comment: Updated my question so that it answers yours. I wasn't aware that the enter event worked similar to the gotfocus - but this doesn't work for me. I am not creating a user control containing two controls. I should probably re-write my question at this point to more accurately explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried the above and it works fine. All you really need are those three event handlers. Just wire them up to the correct controls. I.e. reuse the `OtherControls_Enter` on all other controls within the Custom Control. This assumes of course that the `ListBox` is in the Custom Control.

Answer (score 0):

Implement all control Control_Enter event as centralized and check if a sender object is your textbox or Listbox then listbox will be visible else invisible.

Like this

```
this.button1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.Control_Enter);
   this.textBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.Control_Enter);
   this.listBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.Control_Enter);

private void Control_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control obj = (Control)sender;
        if (obj.Name == "textBox1" || obj.Name == "listBox1")
        {
            listBox1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Dont forget to assign control tab index